Terraform AWS CloudWatch Dashboard widgets giving schema error
AWS CloudWatch Dashboard alarm widgets boundaries highlighted with same color schema of alarm state (Gren, Gray, Red). When writing terraform for the same, it is giving schema error for following widget.
Widget code :
doc_db_free_local_storage = {
    height = 6,
    width  = 6,
    y      = 12,
    x      = 0,
    type   = "metric",
    properties = {
      metrics = [
        [
          "AWS/DocDB", "FreeLocalStorage", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "docdb-2024-03-14-03-20-46"
        ]
      ],
      annotations = {
        alarms = [aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.doc_db_low_available_storage_alarm.arn]
        horizontal = [
          {
            label = "FreeLocalStorage < 10737418240 for 5 datapoints within 10 hours"
            value = 10737418240
          }
        ]
      },
      view    = "timeSeries",
      stacked = false,
      region  = var.aws_region,
      title   = "DocDB - FreeLocalStorage and alarm",
      period  = 300,
      stat    = "Average"
    }
  }

Error:
 Error: Putting dashboard failed: InvalidParameterInput: The dashboard body is invalid, there are 1 validation errors:
 [
   {
     "dataPath": "/widgets/8/properties",
     "message": "Should match exactly one schema in oneOf"
   }
 ]
       status code: 400, request id: a4c14b5e-d060-40a4-8062-c2be5f14df4c
 
   with module.cloudwatch_dashboard.aws_cloudwatch_dashboard.main,
   on intelligent-data-store/ids-source.tf line 271, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "main":
   271: resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "main" {
 

property alarms when kept outside the annotations, things are working fine except the boundaries are not being highlighted. Manually editing the source is somehow working.
Working:
doc_db_free_local_storage = {
    height = 6,
    width  = 6,
    y      = 12,
    x      = 0,
    type   = "metric",
    properties = {
      metrics = [
        [
          "AWS/DocDB", "FreeLocalStorage", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "docdb-2024-03-14-03-20-46"
        ]
      ],
      alarms = [aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.doc_db_low_available_storage_alarm.arn],
      annotations = {
                horizontal = [
          {
            label = "FreeLocalStorage < 10737418240 for 5 datapoints within 10 hours"
            value = 10737418240
          }
        ]
      },
      view    = "timeSeries",
      stacked = false,
      region  = var.aws_region,
      title   = "DocDB - FreeLocalStorage and alarm",
      period  = 300,
      stat    = "Average"
    }
  }

